# Graph data structure visualization

Tags: graph, visualization

Hello I have got an assignment to write a program, which will visualize a Graph, implemented in any way. I have no problem in implementing Graph, but I have no idea how can I visualize it.

The rules are:
- include graphs with vertex and edge labels, directed and non-directed;
- drawing clarity (avoiding large clusters of vertices and edges, avoiding cutting edges and breaking them in many places)

Do you have any tips or suggestions which language or tool should I use to do it, or when can I find help to deal with this type of problem, I'd be glad. I don't know how to make anything graphic, never done that. I am coding mostly in Java, Python and C++, but I am not advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar problem. The approach I'm working with currently has been first creating a node, then animating it, and repeating for all nodes
https://dl1683.github.io/DataStructuresInJavaScript/index.html.

The Github code might be useful to you. I am not a web dev guy so be careful about doing everything I did.